# Типы данных в функциях Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

объясните пожалуйста почему при разных способах вывода функции, тип переменной меняется с str на Nonetype?

```
def sandvich(*args):
    return (f'В вашем сендвиче следущие компоненты:{args}')

sandvich1 = sandvich('bread', 'ham')

print(sandvich1)
print(type(sandvich1))
```

В вашем сендвиче следущие компоненты:('bread', 'ham')

<class 'str'>

```
def anoher_sandvich(*args):
    print(f'В вашем сендвиче следущие компоненты: {args}')

sandvich1=anoher_sandvich("bread",'eggs')
print(type(sandvich1))
```

В вашем сендвиче следущие компоненты: ('bread', 'eggs')

<class 'NoneType'>

Comment: `anoher_sandvich` не содержит `return`

Comment: Иными словами, если функция ничего не возвращает через return, то она возвращает None.